# Как правильно получить CSV с данными из HTML таблицы?

Tags: python, html, парсер

У меня стоит задача получить .csv с данными из HTML таблицы.

Я из всего не нужного HTML документа смог вытащить таблицу - код парсера:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from bs4.element import Tag
    def open_file():
        html = open('table.html','r' ,encoding='utf-8')
        html_sorted = open('html_sorted.html', 'w+',encoding='utf-8')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find('div', class_='row')
        table = soup.find('table', class_='table')
        table = str(table)
        title = str(title)
        html_sorted.write(title + table)
        html.close()
        html_sorted.close()
    open_file()
```

Каждое утро понедельника у меня будет такая таблица на выходе из которой мне нужно вытягивать данные за последнюю неделю...
[image: Таблица html]

...и помещать в .csv файл в таком виде.
[image: Таблица csv]

Изначально на выходе 10 дат. Если даты идут последовательно, к примеру с 1(понедельник) по 7(воскресенье), то нужен срез за последние 7. На следующей неделе с 8 по 14. А если даты пропускаются, мне нужно в отчет вывести информацию по этим датам с цифрой 0. К примеру в таблице отсутствует 5 число, но в отчете оно нужно со всеми значениями справа в "0".
Мне нужно все данные из  где дата как-то сортировать, добавлять и не потерять привязку к полю с датой остальных полей справа с оценками.
Просто эти самые  с датой ни к какому классу или id не относятся.
Как и tr со всей строкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Прошу помочь подобрать нужные инструменты для решения. С чего начать?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [pandas.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
import pandas as pd

all_tabs_in_page = pd.read_html(url_or_html)
```

Т.к. в общем случае в HTML документе может быть несколько таблиц, `pd.read_html()` всегда возвращает **список** найденных в документе таблиц, даже если в документе всего одна таблица.

Поэтому сначала следует вручную  проверить по какому индексу находиться интересуемая вас таблица. И после этого использовать в коде найденный индекс:

```
df = pd.read_html(url_or_html)[0]
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Используя таким образом модуль Pandas можно легко, быстро и элегантно решать подобные задачи.

То же решение в видн однострочника:

```
pd.read_html(url_or_html)[0].to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, с этого и начну!